# Why does Rust have an infinite loop construct?

Tags: syntax, language-comparison, control-flow, loops, rust

The Rust programming language has an infinite loop construct, which looks like this:

```rust
loop {
   <some code>
}
```

It's the only language I can think of that has dedicated syntax for this; in most other languages some variation of `while true` is used instead. Why does Rust have it?

Comment: Although it isn't necessarily good practice, note that this can also be replicated in C (and some other languages), such as with `#define forever while (1)` and then you can just do `forever { ... }`

Comment: Ruby has this too

Comment: QBasic has something similar with `DO ... LOOP`, although you can also add a `WHILE` or `UNTIL` condition to either the `DO` or the `LOOP`.

Comment: Ada has loop ... end loop, in part because of exit (C/Rust break)/return statements and in part because of a need to loop infinitely in some low-level programs.

Comment: Go also has `for { ... }` which is the same as `for ;; { ...}`.

Comment: Turing also has `loop ... end loop`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The rust `loop {}` syntax has a unique feature: it has a return value. Consider this code:

```rs
let val = loop {
   let random_number = rng::random();
   if random_number < 0.5 {
       break random_number;
   }
}
```

This will set val to the first random number below 0.5. This wouldn't work for any other kind of loop since they could potentially exit before hitting a `break`.

Other languages don't have this because they have statements distinct from expressions, so loops don't return anything. In rust all other loops return `()`

This feature was actually added later, initially the `loop{}` construct existed as the only way to create a `!` "never" type.

Comment: Great answer! I actually used it for exactly this just yesterday, to implement Parsec's `many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]` in Rust. Loop until you get an `Err` then break and check the error.

Comment: Worth adding that `while` loops cannot have the same feature, because they might terminate without breaking. A language *could* have `while` loops which produce optional values, but this would be inconvenient for the use-case where the only loop exit is a `break` which does produce a value.

Comment: `while` and `for` loops could have the same feature if they also have an `else` clause, which only executes when the loop does not exit via `break`. Python is the most well known language that supports an `else` clause after loops, but the only language I'm aware of that also supports `while ... else` and `for ... else` returning values is Zig.

Comment: One way this could possibly be implemented for `while` loops is using the value of the last expression in the block if it terminates due to the condition (like other constructs do). E.g., `let mut x = 10; while x > 4 { x -= 1; x * 2 }` would return `8`

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms What if the loop runs 0 times?

Comment: @mousetail Oh, fair...I suppose you could have it wrap the output in an `Option` and do `None` if it never runs...this would probably work more optimally with a `do while`, but that's basically just a `loop` anyway

Comment: This explanation is anachronistic. Return values were only [added to `loop` in 2016](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1624), so they cannot be possibly the reason the `loop` construct exists in the first place.

Comment: It's the main purpose now though

Answer (score 8):

`loop` was [originally added](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1906) to Rust to allow for functions whose body was an infinite loop to not need a `return` statement after the loop. Other languages get around this by treating loops as definitely infinite only when the controlling expression is the literal `true` (e.g. [Dart](https://godbolt.org/z/hEshfcYnG), [TypeScript](https://godbolt.org/z/zK7738j5f)) or a compile-time constant that evaluates to true (e.g. [JLS§14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22-300-Q), [Zig](https://godbolt.org/z/8qM9qqWhd), [D](https://godbolt.org/z/KK7TW9Y9j)).

Answer (score 4):

While `loop` may have been added with returning values in mind, making this just a bonus, infinitely looping until a `break` is encountered is pretty common across languages (with constructs like `while (1)` or `for (;;)` likely being familiar to most), and giving this dedicated syntax saves keystrokes and improves readability.

E.g., Ruby has this `loop` syntax (along with a similarly sugary `until`), yet doesn't have the value-returning feature, showing that the readability advantage is itself worth considering in a vacuum.

Comment: [It was not added with returning values in mind, though.](/q/698/799#comment2296_702)